msbuild command is coping all the non required folder to out path of another folder
i have a monolith solution that has 2 kinds of projects:

running of 4.8 .net framework
running on 3.1 .net core

for projects running on 4.8 has output path is "c:\product"
for a project running on 3.1 .net core has output path is "c:\product\Remotepatching" and it has project dependency of one of the 4.8 .net framework project.
msbuild command:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" "C:\Sources\APM.sln" /p:platform="x64" /p:configuration="release"
when I'm running the above cmd to build the solution, all the folder from "c:\product" is also getting copied to "c:\product\Remotepatching".
but if I remove the project dependency from the 3.1 .net core project those folders doesn't get copied.
is there any thing I'm missing in msbuild command?
the project file for RemotePatching project
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProductSubdirectory>RemotePatching</ProductSubdirectory>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>Properties\StrongNameKey.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <StartupObject />
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
    <DelaySign>false</DelaySign>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>..\..\Product\RemotePatching\</OutputPath>
    <CheckForOverflowUnderflow>true</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;$(BuildServerConstants)</DefineConstants>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <WarningsAsErrors />
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>..\..\Product\RemotePatching\</OutputPath>
    <CheckForOverflowUnderflow>true</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;$(BuildServerConstants)</DefineConstants>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="PlatformServices">
      <HintPath>..\..\Product\PlatformServices.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


The .Net Core 3.1 is an SDK-style project. SDK-style projects support copying transitive dependencies.
Add the following to your .Net Core 3.1 project to turn off this feature.
<PropertyGroup>
  <DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>true</DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>
</PropertyGroup>

See the DisableTransitiveProjectReferences documentation and the ProjectReference documentation for more detail.

with this change the folder and exe which was suppose to sit inside "c:\product\Remotepatching" is moving out in "c:\product". as well.
eg:RemotePatchingServiceConfiguration folder should remain inside "c:\product\Remotepatching" but post above mentioned change it's getting copied to  "c:\product" as well
